# Excel: which products are most frequently ordered together? (clustering question)

Tags: clustering, excel, similarities, frequency

I'd like to recruit your help in coming up with an Excel-based method to analyse a set of raw ordering data where each item is on its own row.

So, in the data below, order 111 contains two part numbers, ABC and DEF, in quantities of 2 and 3, respectively.

```
Order Number | Part Number | Quantity |
111          | ABC         |     2    |
111          | DEF         |     3    |
222          | ABC         |     1    |
333          | ABC         |     4    |
333          | DEF         |     4    |
```

You can think of ABC as peanut butter and DEF as jelly. Usually they're ordered in a 1:1 ratio, but someone may be a heavy peanut butter user and only order peanut butter (as in order 222).

The part number array is large, let's say in the several hundreds (peanut butter, jelly, apple butter, fluffernutter, lemon curd, whatever).

I'd like to be able to answer:

- For a given part number (ABC, for example) what is the most commonly ordered
  partner part number (peanut butter, ABC, is usually paired with jelly, DEF, 83% of the time, apple butter, 3%, by itself 14%) and
- What is the ratio of the queried part number against its partner? (peanut butter:jelly = 0.8 because jelly goes faster usually)

Comment: What do you mean by `Excel-based method`? You are asking for a Excel code/script/functions?

Comment: Hi, ttnphns, unfortunately, my only tool available for data analysis is Excel, so in trying to come up with a solution, I'm trying to rely on functions native to that software environment.

Comment: [Multiple correspondence analysis](http://wwwpub.utdallas.edu/~herve/Abdi-MCA2007-pretty.pdf) is an exploratory technique often used for looking at what kind of products tend to be bought together. Functions available in R's `MASS` & [`ca`](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v20/i03/paper) packages, the latter providing some variations on standard MCA; `PROC CORRESP` in SAS also. Don't know if there's perhaps a plug-in for Excel.

Comment: In fact there is: [xlstat](http://www.xlstat.com/en/learning-center/tutorials/running-a-multiple-correspondence-analysis-mca-with-xlstat.html)

Comment: Is Excel a strict requirement or just what you have? In the second case, I would suggest giving R a try. It is free and open-source, and much better for statistical analysis.

Comment: ## Wrong tool. Excel is about the worst choice for data mining. ## Wrong task. You are *not* looking for *clusters*, but for **frequent itemset mining**. A different task, and well covered in literature, with plenty of tools.

Comment: This is a fill-in-the-wizard application called a "Pivot Table." Just follow the directions.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, thanks very much. Seems that Tanagra has an Excel plug in that will pull the Excel dataset into its analysis suite and spit back the right itemsets.

For those reading later, I downloaded Tanagra here: http://eric.univ-lyon2.fr/~ricco/tanagra/en/contenu_telechargement_logiciel_tanagra.html

The Excel plug-in is found in the installation directory, so you'll need to direct Excel to that directory to add the .xla file as an add-in.

There's an article here about how to do the frequent itemset mining: http://eric.univ-lyon2.fr/~ricco/tanagra/fichiers/en_Tanagra_Itemset_Mining.pdf

Comment: Just use the real tools right away, instead of relying on plugins. Export to CSV; every tool can read CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, thanks to @Anony-Mousse, I downloaded Tanagra, a French data mining tool (Windows version in my case).

Tanagra can be downloaded here: http://eric.univ-lyon2.fr/~ricco/tanagra/en/tanagra.html

I then installed the Tanagra plug-in to Excel. As an FYI, the plug-in is found within the main software package's install directory, so look there if you get confused. There are plenty of tutorials about how to install plug-ins to Excel on the Web. I used Excel 2010. No problems.

After that, I read up on their frequent itemsets FAQ: http://eric.univ-lyon2.fr/~ricco/tanagra/fichiers/en_Tanagra_Itemset_Mining.pdf

In uploading my information, I had a slight problem which was when uploading from my spreadsheet, null values were blank, not zero, so when importing the data, it classified the content as discrete rather than continuous. I'm not sure if there's a way to resolve the problem with the data classified as discrete, but I did a brute force workaround of replacing blank cells with 0. This made everything work swimmingly and I got my itemsets.

Another note, since I was looking at all of my orders containing products that may not have been ordered together at all, the SUPPORT (percentage of all orders that contain the itemset) threshhold needed to be set pretty low. For example, if this was for, say, Amazon, and they sell 1000 orders of sandwich spreads, but only 20 orders of shirts and shorts (but the shirts and shorts are ordered together 100% of the time), you would need to set your threshhold very low (0.02) to be able to pick up on those rare instances. Alternatively, you could clean your data up to exclude clothing (in this case) so that you'd have clearer groupings.

Thanks again for your help, everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Friends don't let friends use Excel for serious statistics.  Yes, that is a slam on the folks in Redmond.  When they fix their pseudorandom number generator I'll take another look at Excel.

Now that that's out of the way, it appears to me that what you want are contingency tables.  That might be manageable if you are only interested in pairwise contingencies.  In higher dimensions it is going to get painful in a hurry.  So, for two dimensions a (very large) pivot-table will get your answers for you.

In higher dimensions, I suspect a database query will be more efficient.  Does Excel permit SQL queries of its tables?

Comment: It does, though this its use is probably beyond my ken:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/data-mining-add-ins-HA010342915.aspx